# How to override a virtual function with a non-virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

Refer to this question: [Hide virtual function with non-virtual override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286173/hide-virtual-function-with-non-virtual-override)

And this question: [override on non-virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530616/override-on-non-virtual-functions)

A function that overrides a virtual function is virtual too, even though it's not explicitly declared virtual.

My technical question is: Is there away to make that overriding function non-virtual (and applies that to classes lower in the hierarchy)? In other words, can I turn the "virtuality" off?

Obviously we can override a non-virtual function with a virtual function. Can we do the opposite, i.e. to override a virtual function with a non-virtual function?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a duplicate of the first one you've linked to. Can you edit your question to explain how it's not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for a way to overrride a virtual function, so that it is no longer virtual.

**Possible approaches using inheritance**

Unfortunately, you cannot get rid of the virtuality of the member function once it is declared virtual.  This is a direct consequence of the C++ Standard:

> 10.3/2:  If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, **derived directly or indirectly** from Base,
>   a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list ,
>   cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is
>   declared, then Derived::vf is **also virtual**.

The use of `final` will not solve your problem:  it will just forbid you to override the function in more derived classes.  The function will remain virtual.

There is however an (unconvenient) trick  to remove virtualisation at one specific level, using multiple inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};
class C : public B { 
public:
    void foo() { cout << "C" << endl; }
};
class EH {   // Helper class, does not derive from A 
public:      // so foo() is non virtual here
    void foo() {   cout << "EH!" << endl; }
};
class E : public B, public EH { // inherits the virtual foo and the non virtual one
public:
    using EH::foo;     // We just say to use the non virtual one
};
```

The class E inherits from both the virtual and the non virtual.  We just say to use the non virtual one if one calls it:

```
E e; 
e.foo();          // calls the non virtual function EH::foo(); => EH!
B* pb2 = &e; 
pb2->foo();       // calls the original virtual function B::foo() => B
```

Be aware that this trick works **only for the current level**: If you'd derive a class form E, the class would also inherit indirectly from A, and here is the virtual curse again !

**What do you intend to achieve ?**

With virtual functions, you ensure that you always call the appropriate function corresponding to the real idendity of your object, regardless the fact that you use a pointer to a base.  That's the goal of polymorphism.

With non-virtual function, your compiler invokes the function he thinks is the correct one, according to the type you are accessing to.  If you access the object via a valid base pointer it will hence use the function of the base class instead of the derived one.  Is this really what you want ?

if yes, just do this:

```
C c;
B* pb = &c;
pb->foo();         // uses the virtual function
pb->B::foo();      // but you can force to use the function, ignoring the virtuality.
```

**Possible approach using a virtual and a non virtual function**

With little additional cost you could emulate this behaviour in your code, using a comibnation of 2 functions: a private virtual one, and a public non virtual:

```
class A {
    virtual void foo2() { cout << "A" << endl; }  // virtual function
public:  
    void foo() { foo2(); } // non virtual function calling the virtual one 
};
class B : public A {
    void foo2() { cout << "B" << endl; }  // overriding virtual
};
class C : public B { 
public:
    void foo() { cout << "C" << endl; }   // ignore the virtual and override the non virtual function :-) 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ introduced `final`. I've not used it, but that's your solution. The method is still virtual but it can't be overridden.

Comment: Not what I meant. I meant a function that can be overriden the same way that we override non-virtual function (and without using 'override' identifier). Or do you call that "hiding" instead of "overriding"?
 
That's a technical question though, I don't actually have a scenario for its usage.

Comment: One can't turn off the virtuality, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I cooked up an example but then discovered that it was identical to the one already provided by Paul Evans, except that I prefer `auto` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the c++11 `final`, Something like:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo();
};

struct B : A {
    void foo() final;       // virtual overrides A::foo
};

struct C : B {
    void foo();             // error: can't override
};
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my technical answer no,if we do not override the virtual function in the derived class then then the vitable of the derived class would contains the address of the base class virtual function.