# Overriding a virtual function but not a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, using, virtual-functions

I'm attempting to derive a class `C` from two classes, `A` and `B`; after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28618981/14256449), I attempted to write `using B::<function>` in order to override a pure virtual function in `A` with the implementation in `B`.

However, the approach in that answer does not work for *pure* virtual functions; in that case, I found that I needed to be more explicit.
So evidently `using` can resolve ambiguity, but it can't introduce an implementation?
I was just hoping to better understand what is going on here.

```cpp
struct A {

    // this would result in ambiguity:
    //virtual void e(void) const {}   // ERROR: member 'e' found in multiple base classes 

    // resolving ambiguity with 'using'
    virtual void f(void) const {}     // OK

    // this would result in an unimplemented method:
    //virtual void g(void) const = 0; // ERROR: variable type 'C' is an abstract class

    // *** why doesn't this work? ***
    //virtual void h(void) const = 0; // ERROR: variable type 'C' is an abstract class

    // resolving ambiguity by explicitly defining what I want
    virtual void i(void) const = 0;   // OK
};
struct B {    
    void e(void) const {}
    void f(void) const {}
    void g(void) const {}
    void h(void) const {}
    void i(void) const {}
};
struct C : public A, public B {
    using B::f;                    // sufficient to pin down 'f'
    using B::h;                    // not sufficient to pin down 'h'
    void i(void) const { B::i(); } // sufficient to pin down 'i'
};
int main() {
    C X;
    X.e();
    X.f();
    X.g();
    X.h();
    X.i();
}
```

Comment: ***not sufficient to pin down 'h'*** what do you mean by "pin down"?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Your example seems to work just fine and do what you would expect it to do. https://ideone.com/RqXpFe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I attempted to write using `B::<function>` in order to override a pure
> virtual function in A with the implementation in B.

You misunderstood. It is not possible to *override* a function this way. All that `using B::h;` does: it introduces `B::h` into the scope of `struct C`, so that `X.h();` in `main()` becomes equivalent to `X.B::h();`. So, `A::h()` remains pure virtual, thus you cannot instantiate `struct C`.